# ACPI state S5 is really powered off?

Tags: acpi

I saw this on a system:

```
ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S5
```

but I didn't see this on other systems when pressed the power button.

what's the difference between ACPI S5 and normal powered-off state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S5 is [soft off](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface#Global_states), *i.e.* most of the system is powered off but the power supply still provides power so that the power button can be used to turn the system on. In general, power is also provided to a system controller so that the system can be powered on using the keyboard, wake-on-LAN, RTC alarms etc.

Whether that’s “normal powered-off state” depends on your definition of that. Going by your comment,

> the "normal powered-off state" here I mean the system doesn't support S5, but the user also presses the power button to power off the system.

since a system which doesn’t support S5 is a system which doesn’t support ACPI, the difference between S5 and “normal powered-off state”, at least on a PC, is that the latter is a “mechanical off” state, *i.e.* power is cut at the PSU.

Technically such a PC could also be an APM-driven PC, in which case pressing the power switch could also enter a “soft off” state. But all PCs built in the last two decades or so support ACPI.

Comment: the "normal powered-off state" here I mean the system doesn't support S5, but the user also presses the power button to power off the system.

Comment: All ACPI systems support S5, it’s a basic requirement in the spec.

Comment: How about the system didn't support ACPI, since I didn't see this line "ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S5" in all systems, I want to know their differences when powered off.